# Flume - Multiple sinks and channels for single agent

Tags: ruby, puppet, erb, flume, flume-ng

Im trying to set up flume such that each agent can have multiple sinks and eventually multiple channels and sources (for now looking at only multiple channels ). I have a config file which looks like [this](http://pastie.org/10315204) and a [ruby template](http://pastie.org/10315209). I am confused about how to go about and add the functionality to the template file such that each agent can send an event to multiple channels

Comment: You can describe multiple channel to one source with `agent.sources.app-log-source.channels = channel1 channel2`. Is that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your flume agent, your source will basically push data to multiple agent. FlumeNG by default support multiplexing the events into different channels. There are two options available for that:

1. **Replicating Source**: Replicate all data from your source to all the channels
2. **Selective Pushing**: Selectively push some data to your channels on the basis of some conditions

The syntax for that in flume would be something like this:

```
dataplatform.sources.source1.selector.type = replicating (or multiplexing)
```

(assuming the agent name is dataplatform)

You can route the data from your source to multiple channels in this way:

```
dataplatform.sources.source1.channels = channel1 channel2 channel3
```

For further details on this, please refer to flume-ng user guide : https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

Comment: I went through the guide and was able to configure multiple channels. Any idea how to link each channel to multiple sinks? I can ask a separate question if have a solution

Comment: One channel in flume can write to multiple sinks, but that capability is generally there for load balancing or failover.  Check out Flume Sink Processors in the user guide